# How to send email template multipe times to same list in Constant Contact?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, constantcontact

I am running into an issue where I need to programmatically send the same email campaign to multiple people on a list that are the same via people(same email addresses) multiple times. Constant Contact is not letting me do this.

Example:

I want to use the same birthday campaign year after year and send it out once a year to everyone on my list. However according to the Constant Contact documentation I can only send the email campaign once too new email addresses.

Is there something in the API documentation that will let me do this?

So far all I have encountered is that I need to delete the email campaign, and recreate it using this API command: `http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/email-campaigns/email-campaigns-collection.html?method=POST`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the Constant Contact api's there is no way to send the same email campaign to the same contact multiple times.

However for the example that you have given there is an [automation platform](https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/6179-create-a-recurring-birthday-email?q=birthday*&lang=en_US) within Constant Contact that will automatically send out a birthday email, but at this time there is no way to programmatically set that up.

If you need to do it programmatically I would create a new campaign for each year, especially since deleting and recreating just creates a new campaign anyway.